# Dual of the Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

It is well known that for a given bounded domain $\Omega$, the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space, which is the space given by
$$
W^{1,2}(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega):\nabla u\in L^2(\Omega)\}
$$
under the norm
$$
\|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}=\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$
Then by Riesz representation theorem, the dual of this space should be isomorphic to the space itself. But I have seen in PDE books, the dual of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a bigger space than $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, which is also not isomorphic to $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, if I understood correctly. I could not understand the reason.

Can someone please help me to understand the concept of it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not quite that the $W^{1,2}$ norm is the sum of the $L^2$ norm of the function and the $L^2$ norm of its derivative... but, rather, that the norm-squared is the sum of the squares of those two norms. Also, some typos, $W^{k,2}$ should be $W^{1,2}$, evidently. But, anyway, those typoze do not affect the sense of your question. :)

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the typos. I hope the norm you mentioned is equivalent to the above norm. If you have some explanation about the question, kindly explain. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the sum-of-norms norm is _not_ topologically equivalent to the square-root of sums of squares norm... Maybe check your source? More later...

Comment: @paulgarrett These norms are of course equivalent as the $\ell_1$ norm and the $\ell_2$ norm on $\mathbb R^2$ are.

Comment: @MaoWao, ah, hm, perhaps so! Still, then, the sum-norm does not literally give a Hilbert-space structure...? In particular, _why_ use the sum-of-norms norm at all?

Comment: @MaoWao, ah, yes, indeed, the two are topologically equivalent, for the reason you say. :) :)

Comment: You have to be careful about what topology you're taking the dual with. This notion of duality comes from taking the dual pairing to be the (real) $L^2$ pairing, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740355/dual-of-h1-0-h-1-or-h-01?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

All infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic and the dual of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a separable Banach space. Thus, it is also isomorphic to $L^2(\Omega)$, $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$...

However, these different identifications result in different duality mappings. Therefore, it is recommended that you do not identify the dual spaces of $W^{k,2}(\Omega)$ for $k > 0$ with itself. You should only identify $L^2(\Omega)^*$ with $L^2(\Omega)$. In this way, you get a continuous embedding
$$
E \colon W^{1,2}(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)
$$
and the adjoint mapping $E^* \colon L^2(\Omega) \to W^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$ (here, we used the identification of $L^2(\Omega)^*$)
is continuous and injective. Thus, you can identify $L^2(\Omega)$ with a subspace of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$. Hence, $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is smaller than $L^2(\Omega)$, which is (in this sense) smaller than $W^{1,2}(\Omega)^*$.

Comment: Of course not all separable Banach spaces are isometrically isomorphic, but all separable *infinite-dimensional Hilbert* spaces are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @MaoWao: Yes, of course...